# Cannot execute php files in wp-content

Tags: php, security, permissions

Something blocks my php files from executing in wp-content folder including plugins and themes folders. If I create a new php file in wp-content, and try to access it like this /wp-content/test.php, it get's redirected to a not found page.

I've already check file permissions and .htaccess and couldn't find anything wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: code of plugins files go in `wp_content/plugins/nameOfPlugin/file.php` and not directly in `wp_content`

Comment: that's true, the problem is it does not work for any plugin for any path that includes wp-content folder. the above is just a simplification

Comment: Can you check if you are able to execute file through command line?

Comment: Unfortunately, just having FTP access to it. It looks like index.php can be only run directly, other files are somehow restricted, can it be some setting on Apache?